# Dynamic tables with buttons in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I would like to construct a table with buttons/input boxes in AngularJS. 
In the first column it should have some category names ID, Name, Gender. Columns 2-5 should have several input (for ID or Name) or drop boxes for gender. Headline of each column in something like Person1, Person2, Person3 and Person4.

I was trying to do this via ng-repeat in AngularJS but I do not know how to setup this appropriately.

Moreover, I need to do this that the persons are listed in columns..

My basic code is at least for the data (and the data should be editable):

```
$scope.data = [{
  "person":"person1",
  "characteristics":[{"_id": "001"}, {"name":"Andi"}, {"gender":"Male"}]
},[{
  "person":"person2",
  "characteristics":[{"_id": "002"}, {"name":"Ben"}, {"gender":"Male"}]
}];
```

I found some fiddle examples, but none of them worked for me..
Does anything have a clue how I could start?

Many thanks and cheers,
Andi

Answer (score 0):

I had to take some liberties with your data because I couldn't see the need for the structure as it was

```
$scope.data = [{
person: "person1",characteristics: {_id: "001",name: "Andi",gender: "Male"}},{
person: "person2",characteristics: {_id: "002",name: "Ben",gender: "Male"}}]
```

Then the html, while not very elegant, would be something like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-sm-10">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th ng-repeat="p in data">{{ p.person }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td ng-repeat="c in data"><input type="text" ng-model="c.characteristics._id" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td ng-repeat="c in data"><input type="text" ng-model="c.characteristics.name" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```